How to get total activity duration for a group of contacts
In the CRM, we systematically enter the duration of each activity we have for all our contacts: how do we find the overall time spent for each group of contacts? I remain at your disposal and thank you in advance for your response.


Go to SearchKit
Search for Activities
Group by your criteria
Add the "duration" field as a column, and choose "Sum" as the aggregate function


Thank you for your response ! However, I use CIVICRM and don't know about Searchkit, sorry. Is it possible to find the overall duration of all activities entered in a group's contacts using CIVICRM? Usually I use "advanced search" but there is also "search builder" which is less intuitive. Thanks in advance, sorry for my English, I'm French and not an expert!

SearchKit is part of CiviCRM. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/searching/searchkit/what-is-searchkit/

Pourriez-vous me passer des copies d'écrans car les explications en anglais ne sont pas claires pour moi ? je suis vraiment désolé.
